# Adding subroutine to hyperlink not working

Tags: excel, hyperlink, vba

I'm trying to add a hyperlink to a name which would be linked to a subroutine. When a user clicks on the hyperlinked name, the subroutine would be called.

Right now, I can hyperlink a cell and I have some code that would show a message box but nothing is appearing when I click on the hyperlinked cell.

["Assign macro to hyperlink" tutorial I'm using](http://learnexcelmacro.com/wp/2012/04/assign-macro-to-hyperlink/)

**Simplified Code:**

```
Sub Main()
    Call SetHyperlink
End Sub

Sub SetHyperlink()
    Range("A6").Select
    ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection, Address:="", SubAddress:="$A$6", TextToDisplay:="TEST"  
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_FollowHyperlink(ByVal Target As Hyperlink)
    'Check if the Target Address is same as you have given
    'In the above example i have taken A4 Cell, so I am
    'Comparing this with $A$4

    If Target.Range.Address = "$A$6" Then
        'Write your all VBA Code, which you want to execute
        'Or Call the function or Macro which you have
        'written or recorded.
        MsgBox "Write your Code here to be executed"
        Exit Sub
    End If
End Sub
```

I'm still very new to vba so if it's something obvious please let me know the reasoning as well. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Would it be ok to just run the macro when the cell is clicked?  Or are you trying to have multiple of these hyperlinks in a cell.

Comment: I would like for the `Worksheet_FollowHyperlink` sub to be run when the hyperlinked cell "A6" is clicked

Comment: Are you sure the hyperlink was created on the same sheet where the `Worksheet_FollowHyperlink` code resides? Or did you place the `Worksheet_FollowHyperlink` code in the `Worksheet` Module itself or in a standard module? Because it works as written for me :)

Comment: @ScottHoltzman I'm not sure, how can I check? There are multiple worksheets so it sounds like that might be it.

Comment: It works for me as well.  in the code view you need to paste that Sub in "Sheet1" vs "Module1" (Under Microsoft Excel Objects).  It is that tree on the far left.

Comment: @PhilipBrack I see that all of my code is in Module1 and I can copy it to Sheet27(Report1) which is where I want it but that sheet is generated by another sub. So, if I delete that sheet and rerun the macro to regenerate it I don't think my code will still be there will it?

Comment: fastest way, right click on the sheet tab and select view code, that is the worksheet module. `Worksheet_FollowHyperlink` belongs in the worksheet module

Comment: @JonathanPorter - You can place it in the `Workbook_SheetFollowHyperlink` module in the `ThisWorkbook` object. This will call for any hyperlink clicked in any sheet. You can further filter actions taken by specific sheet using the `sh` variable. This will reside in the workbook all the time and work for newly created or existing sheets.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman thank you for your answer. Would you be willing to show an example as an answer so that others can also see it there instead of digging through the comments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the workbook module, using this code will check the hyperlink text and then call the macro according to the hyperlink selection.

```
    Private Sub Workbook_SheetFollowHyperlink(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Hyperlink)
    Select Case Target.TextToDisplay
    Case "hi"
        MsgBox "Hi"
    Case "Oranges"
        MsgBox "You selected oranges"
    Case "Banana"
        MsgBox "Banana"
    Case "Trees"
        MsgBox "Tree"
    End Select

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: I am not sure what you mean Jonathan